# What is RELIEF stands for?

Tags: pattern-recognition, feature-selection

I recently applied a feature selection algorithm called 'RELIEF' for my pattern recognition problem for comparison. The wiki page of 'RELIEF' can be found here [RELIEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief_%28feature_selection%29#cite_note-1). But search the Internet, I couldn't find what is RELIEF stands for. Even in the original [paper](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/kira1992.pdf) I couldn't find it. Does anyone knows this abbreviation? Thanks a lot.

A.

Comment: What if it simply isn't an abbreviation? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a name for a feature selection algorithm, and it's not an abbreviation for any other words as far as I know. Additionally, in the original paper **'RELIEF'** is also written as **'Relief'**. This also proves my point of view.